# Storyboard doesn't contain a view controller with identifier "SideMenuController"

Tags: swift, uikit, storyboard

Message:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Storyboard (<UIStoryboard: 0x6000036306c0>) doesn't contain a view controller with identifier 'HomeViewController''

I try to add side menu view to my MainViewController and get an error while doing that.

Code:

```
guard UIStoryboard(name: "MainViewController", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SideMenuViewController") is SideMenuViewController else {
    fatalError("Unable to Instantiate Quotes View Controller")
}
```

I set all identifiers and they work, but only that part of code doesn't work.
I tried: clean building folder, set another identifier, use another storyboard and nothing helps.

[image]

Comment: Confusing: the error message you quote is complaining about `HomeViewController` but you're asking about `SideMenuViewController` (or maybe `SideMenuController`).  Also, is `MainViewController` really the name of the storyboard?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.